# How to combine Toggler and Button?

Tags: gui-construction, button

The Play function defines a toggle button to start and stop:

[image]

I'm trying to emulate that, but with a single button. I feel like this is a common enough task that this question should be answered somewhere (but I can't find it).

**Question:** I'd like a single button that toggles between (at least two) states: where each state has a different image and each performs a different action when clicked. The api could be this:

```
StateButton[<|ImageA -> ActionA, ImageB -> ActionB, ...|>]
```

Here was a first attempt using just row which uses nasty hacks to center the "play symbol":

```
startStop[startAction_,stopAction_] := 
            Row[{Button["\!\(\*
        StyleBox[AdjustmentBox[\"\[RightPointer]\",\nBoxBaselineShift->0.12313612313612314`,\nBoxMargins->{{0., 0.}, {-0.12313612313612314`, 0.12313612313612314`}}],\nFontSize->24]\)", 
startAction,Appearance->"Frameless",ImageSize->{30,30},Alignment->Center],
Button["\!\(\*AdjustmentBox[\(\[FilledSquare]\),\nBoxBaselineShift->-0.1704961704961705,\nBoxMargins->{{0., 0.}, 
{0.1704961704961705, -0.1704961704961705}}]\)",stopAction,Appearance->"Frameless",ImageSize->{30,30},Alignment->Center]}," ",BaselinePosition->Center]
```

I have tried wrapping `Button` and `Toggler` together in various obvious ways e.g. `Toggler[Dynamic[x], {Button[1, Print[1]], Button[2, Print[2]]}]` which don't work - I cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out it was easy to replicate the buttons from `Play`:

```
$playView=ToExpression@GraphicsBox[
        TagBox[{
          {GrayLevel[0.9], RectangleBox[{5, -158}, {29, -135}]}, 
          {GrayLevel[0.3], 
           PolygonBox[NCache[{{13, -153}, {13, -140}, {21, Rational[-293, 2]}, {13, -153}}, {{13, -153}, {13, -140}, {21, -146.5}, {13, -153}}]]}, 
          {GrayLevel[0.5], 
           StyleBox[LineBox[{{5, -158}, {5, -135}, {29, -135}, {29, -158}, {5, -158}}],
            Antialiasing->False]}},
         Null],
        ImageSize->{29.4921875, Automatic}];

    $stopView=ToExpression@GraphicsBox[
         TagBox[{
           {GrayLevel[0.9], RectangleBox[{34, -158}, {58, -135}]}, 
           {GrayLevel[0.3], RectangleBox[{42, -150}, {50, -143}]}, 
           {GrayLevel[0.5], 
            StyleBox[LineBox[{{34, -158}, {34, -135}, {58, -135}, {58, -158}, {34, -158}}],
             Antialiasing->False]}},
          Null]];


Clear[cycleState]
SetAttributes[cycleState, HoldFirst]
cycleState[s_ /; s > 0, len_: 2] := (s = If[s >= len, 1, s + 1])

DynamicModule[{views = {$playView, $stopView}, state = 1},
     Button[Dynamic[views[[state]]], 
      Switch[state, 1, Print@"start", 2, Print@"stop"]; 
      cycleState[state], Appearance -> "Palette"]
     ]
```

Comment: Might even be easier to use a Trigger control which is designed to handle this kind of behavior.

Answer (score 1):

My solution uses `SetterBar` with the items framed.

```
{SetterBar[Dynamic[x], 
 {"Play" -> Framed[Rotate["\[FilledUpTriangle]", -\[Pi]/2]], 
  "Stop" -> Framed@"\[FilledSquare]"}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20}], 
Dynamic@Switch[x, "Play", Style["Play", Green], "Stop", Style["Stop", Red]]}
```

It is pretty close. I'm certain you can tweak the font size to get it identical. It is probably what is used behind the scenes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: There are multiple buttons, the question asks for a single button.